# Rotating an image while scrolling

Tags: javascript, animation, css, scroll

On this website http://www.contrastrebellion.com/ about half way through there is a circle that rotates depending on how far down or up you scroll the page. How can this be achieved without having to rely on Facebook like this site does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature was implemented in http://www.contrastrebellion.com/public/js/script.js?2

Look at the code block starting with

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
```

It uses [jQuery `.scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and [CSS transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) (including the browser-specific versions of it) for the effect.

<sup>Side note: it fails to do any of the JS magic in my main browser, because I'm blocking Facebook domains. Moral of the story: don't make your *entire* JS depend on one small subset of your sites featureset.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, It makes no sense that they based it relies on Facebook any ideas how to achieve the same effect without Facebook

Comment: @Marcus: **that** effect doesn't depend on Facebook, but their initial JS tries (among other things) to initialize the FB integration and when that fails (as it does for me, since the necessary JS file is not loaded), then the rest of that initialization doesn't run and the effects are never set up.

Comment: Oh ok I see so far ive stripped the site down to just the animation but im having some problems getting it to work, thanks ill figure it out

Answer (score 0):

They are using the CSS3-property `transform` with a rotation value based on the current scroll position.